# connected set in the complex plane

Tags: diagrams, draw

I am trying to make the following diagram, with a domain
[image]

take a screenshot, because I don't know how to put the code
[image]

I have done this in matcha, but I want to place the domain a little more topological.

```
tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,349); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 349

%Straight Lines [id:da6992700303297221] 
\draw    (78.11,181.02) -- (189.11,174.57) ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp6642840789302853] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}] (30.69,183.54) .. controls (29.29,157.35) and (49.4,134.99) .. (75.59,133.6) .. controls (101.78,132.21) and (124.13,152.32) .. (125.52,178.5) .. controls (126.92,204.69) and (106.81,227.05) .. (80.62,228.44) .. controls (54.43,229.83) and (32.08,209.73) .. (30.69,183.54) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp6495481894460198] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}] (103.01,139.14) .. controls (108.71,135.78) and (115.23,133.65) .. (122.26,133.14) .. controls (146.89,131.37) and (168.33,150.24) .. (170.13,175.29) .. controls (171.93,200.35) and (153.43,222.09) .. (128.79,223.87) .. controls (120.88,224.44) and (113.3,222.88) .. (106.6,219.67) -- (125.52,178.5) -- cycle ; \draw  [dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}] (103.01,139.14) .. controls (108.71,135.78) and (115.23,133.65) .. (122.26,133.14) .. controls (146.89,131.37) and (168.33,150.24) .. (170.13,175.29) .. controls (171.93,200.35) and (153.43,222.09) .. (128.79,223.87) .. controls (120.88,224.44) and (113.3,222.88) .. (106.6,219.67) ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp028167613747934084] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}] (146.01,137.14) .. controls (151.71,133.78) and (158.23,131.65) .. (165.26,131.14) .. controls (189.89,129.37) and (211.33,148.24) .. (213.13,173.29) .. controls (214.93,198.35) and (196.43,220.09) .. (171.79,221.87) .. controls (163.88,222.44) and (156.3,220.88) .. (149.6,217.67) -- (168.52,176.5) -- cycle ; \draw  [dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}] (146.01,137.14) .. controls (151.71,133.78) and (158.23,131.65) .. (165.26,131.14) .. controls (189.89,129.37) and (211.33,148.24) .. (213.13,173.29) .. controls (214.93,198.35) and (196.43,220.09) .. (171.79,221.87) .. controls (163.88,222.44) and (156.3,220.88) .. (149.6,217.67) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da3136039392760601] 
\draw    (263.6,134.83) -- (424.11,53.02) ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp1828616154616911] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}] (376.69,55.54) .. controls (375.29,29.35) and (395.4,6.99) .. (421.59,5.6) .. controls (447.78,4.21) and (470.13,24.32) .. (471.52,50.5) .. controls (472.92,76.69) and (452.81,99.05) .. (426.62,100.44) .. controls (400.43,101.83) and (378.08,81.73) .. (376.69,55.54) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp6507059531688513] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}] (426.62,100.46) .. controls (423.63,106.36) and (419.27,111.67) .. (413.63,115.88) .. controls (393.82,130.63) and (365.6,126.27) .. (350.59,106.13) .. controls (335.58,85.98) and (339.47,57.69) .. (359.28,42.93) .. controls (365.64,38.2) and (372.86,35.43) .. (380.24,34.52) -- (386.45,79.41) -- cycle ; \draw  [dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}] (426.62,100.46) .. controls (423.63,106.36) and (419.27,111.67) .. (413.63,115.88) .. controls (393.82,130.63) and (365.6,126.27) .. (350.59,106.13) .. controls (335.58,85.98) and (339.47,57.69) .. (359.28,42.93) .. controls (365.64,38.2) and (372.86,35.43) .. (380.24,34.52) ;
%Shape: Polygon Curved [id:ds43359789094645995] 
\draw   (15.6,52.83) .. controls (37.19,56.66) and (448.6,-23.17) .. (471.6,6.83) .. controls (494.6,36.83) and (480.6,241.83) .. (461.6,245.83) .. controls (442.6,249.83) and (-14.4,311.83) .. (14.6,270.83) .. controls (43.6,229.83) and (-6,49) .. (15.6,52.83) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da11792787884022937] 
\draw    (233.6,125.83) -- (263.6,134.83) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da782866538959825] 
\draw    (189.11,174.57) -- (233.6,125.83) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da11834899062732096] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}]  (207.6,26.83) -- (233.6,125.83) ;

% Text Node
\draw (75.49,177) node [anchor=north] [inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$\displaystyle z_{0}$};
% Text Node
\draw (105,177) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$\displaystyle z_{1}$};
% Text Node
\draw (135.61,180.8) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$\displaystyle z_{2}$};
% Text Node
\draw (170.52,179.5) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$\displaystyle z_{3}$};
% Text Node
\draw (243,165) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$\displaystyle L$};
% Text Node
\draw (69,170) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$\displaystyle \smblkcircle $};
% Text Node
\draw (106,169) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$\displaystyle \smblkcircle $};
% Text Node
\draw (131,168) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$\displaystyle \smblkcircle $};
% Text Node
\draw (179,166) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$\displaystyle \smblkcircle $};
% Text Node
\draw (412,45) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$\displaystyle \smblkcircle $};
% Text Node
\draw (383.69,59.54) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$\displaystyle \smblkcircle $};
% Text Node
\draw (393.52,65.5) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$\displaystyle z_{n-1}$};
% Text Node
\draw (426.11,56.02) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$\displaystyle z_{n}$};
% Text Node
\draw (68,17) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$\displaystyle D$};
% Text Node
\draw (225,59) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$\displaystyle d$};
% Text Node
\draw (64.52,135.69) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [rotate=-1.84,xslant=0.14] [align=left] {$\displaystyle N_{0}$};
% Text Node
\draw (119.52,136.69) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [rotate=-1.84,xslant=0.14] [align=left] {$\displaystyle N_{1}$};
% Text Node
\draw (166.52,136.69) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [rotate=-1.84,xslant=0.14] [align=left] {$\displaystyle N_{3}$};
% Text Node
\draw (349.52,54.69) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [rotate=-1.84,xslant=0.14] [align=left] {$\displaystyle N_{n-1}$};
% Text Node
\draw (403.52,11.69) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [rotate=-1.84,xslant=0.14] [align=left] {$\displaystyle N_{ \begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
n\\
\end{array}}$};
% Text Node
\draw (426.11,39.02) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {$\displaystyle P$};


\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: If you want others to help then please post full but minimal exmaples, not sniplets like this there others have to guess the rest before they can even test your code.

Comment: Humble suggestion. Redo the image and enlarge the drawing area as much as possible with Mathcha. To build D you need to add as many points to the closed curve of the drawing tools to get the most topological space.